# My Action Pane keeps popping up at start when I open my Excel VSTO document-level even though I forced it to hide

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I created an "Excel VSTO document-level" project in Visual Studio. I have a pre designed "Action Pane" and a Tab Ribbon with a button in it to show my action pane.

My problem is my action pane keeps popping up (show) at least 1 time and quickly disappears before I do anything.

Here is my code so far in my ribbon:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon

Public Class Ribbon1

    Dim actionsPane1 As New ActionsPaneControl1()

    Private Sub Ribbon1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActionsPane.Clear()
        Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActionsPane.Controls.Add(actionsPane1)
        actionsPane1.Hide()
        Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.DisplayDocumentActionTaskPane = False
    End Sub

    Dim boolAP1toggle As Boolean = True
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If boolAP1toggle = True Then
            Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.DisplayDocumentActionTaskPane = True
            actionsPane1.Show()
            boolAP1toggle = False
        Else
            Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.DisplayDocumentActionTaskPane = False
            actionsPane1.Hide()
            boolAP1toggle = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks eugine. I didn't tried to omit **actionsPan1.Hide()** but I have solved my problem.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to show or hide methods of the pane class. Instead, you need to rely on the [DisplayDocumentActionTaskPane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.displaydocumentactiontaskpane) property which is set to `true` to display the Document Actions task pane; set to `false` to hide the Document Actions task pane.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If boolAP1toggle = True Then
            Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.DisplayDocumentActionTaskPane = True
            boolAP1toggle = False
        Else
            Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.DisplayDocumentActionTaskPane = False
            boolAP1toggle = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake:

```
Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActionsPane.Controls.Add(actionsPane1)
```

will inevitably show Actions Pane at the time when you try to add any form to it, so I needed to add it my **Button1_Click** event handler